# Strange heap memory corruption with vector

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code reports:

> *** glibc detected *** ./cpptest: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00007fffcc49c640 ***

But I can't find any point that could cause heap corruption.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct BigStruct {
    char bytes[128];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<BigStruct> list;
    BigStruct obj;

    list.push_back(obj);
    BigStruct& ref = list.at(0);

    list.push_back(obj);
    ref = list.at(1);

    // To trigger the allocator's error detection
    malloc(100);

    return 0;
}
```

Another code with smaller struct runs without any problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct BigStruct {
    char bytes[64];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<BigStruct> list;
    BigStruct obj;

    list.push_back(obj);
    BigStruct& ref = list.at(0);

    list.push_back(obj);
    ref = list.at(1);

    // To trigger the allocator's error detection
    malloc(100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(100)` why are you doing this ??

Comment: For what do you use malloc and why don't you use the returned pointer of malloc? Btw. you should have a pretty good reason to use malloc()/free() in C++ instead of new/delete. See here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/ for the correct use of malloc, but I don't see in your code why you use malloc.

Comment: Read this: [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), and in particular note this "If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated." This: `ref = list.at(1);` isn't doing what you think. Hint: It isn't reassigning the reference (which isn't possible anyway). The second `push_back` is invalidating the `ref` reference. The ensuing assigning thus invokes undefined behavior on a now-dangling reference.

Comment: When you debug it, what are `&list.at(0)` and `&list.at(1)` and `&ref` right before you do `ref = list.at(1);`? Because when you do `ref =` you aren't reassigning the reference, you are trying to copy what is at `list.at(1)` to what `ref` points to.

Comment: @DumbCoder It triggers the allocator's error detection.

Comment: @RyanP This is only a code block for demonstration, but I don't know why it triggers the allocator's error detection.

Comment: @RyanP is right, the line 'ref = list.at(1)' aren't reassigning the reference, that line is copying, and couurpt the memory, thanks very much!

Comment: @molbdnilo It wasn't there when I commented. The OP has modified the posting.

Comment: @zJay - Did you get the error from the debugger ? Which line exactly ?

Comment: @DumbCoder this line 'malloc(100);'  triggers the error

Comment: This is actually a good question - important issue to be aware of wrt vector and realloc.

Answer (score 5):

You're assigning a value to an object that doesn't exist.

After the second

```
list.push_back(obj);
```

`ref` no longer refers to a valid object - reallocation of the vector's underlying storage moved that object to a different place.
 Using `ref` is undefined from that point.

When you later assign to it

```
ref = list.at(1);
```

you're writing over some memory that is now owned by the memory manager.
When `malloc` tries to allocate memory, it first does a "sanity check" to see if it can detect any disallowed modifications, and it did in this case.